# pointer to member variable vs passing by pointer

Tags: c++

I am wondering which of the both design pattern is more common in the C++ community and in case of doubt which one to prefer over the other. If it depends on the use case, what would make the decission?

```
Class A
{
public:
     A(){createSomeType();}
private:
    SomeType* m_var;
    void createSomeType(){m_var = new SomeType; doSomeThing();}
    void doSomeThing(){m_var->doSomeThing();}
};


Class A
{
public:
    A(){createSomeType();}
private:
    void createSomeType(){SomeType* var = new SomeType; doSomeThing(var);}
    void doSomeThing(SomeType* var){var->doSomeThing();}
};
```

EDIT: Edited avoid UB, as tobi303 pointed out and made member functions private to avoid the question about encapsulation, as others pointed out. This problem is a simplified version. I hope i got it right now.

Comment: I'd say it's a question of ownership semantics.

Comment: The second exposes `SomeType` to the outside world while the first one does not necessarily. If not needed otherwise I would stay with the first. However, I think the example is a bit too simplified, e.g. in the first one, as it is, `doSomeThing()` invokes UB if not called in the correct order.

Comment: I think i have some flaws in the example. I will edit to not be confusing about the flawed example.

Comment: Those two examples are completely different. First is a stateful class, second is stateless. They can not be compared outside of context.

Comment: I was a bit to quick. I edited the code i hope it gets to the point more now.

Answer (score 1):

You would rarely have a method that creates a member variable other than your constructor. Otherwise you run into a series of problems. But your post is not about that.

Apart from that both of your code snippets may have a valid application, at least based on the idea behind it: In the first code example you would create something while the public interface allows manipulating this internal state object. This is probably quite common and normal for encapsulation. `doSomeThing` (also, I would suggest naming it `doSomething`) could be some method to calculate some figures which might be done at the initialization and sometimes later, too, which could explain the fact that the method is part of the public interface.

In your second code snippet, `var` seems to be a somewhat temporary variable because you immediately use `doSomeThing` with a parameter to operate on it. It is less common to have `doSomething` be a public member function of the class. In which case would a class be able to create and immediately change an object and offer the same change operation for an outsider? Quite rarely, this is the case.

By using a variable that is not an attribute you basically say: This variable is not part of the state of the class, it is nothing that will persist outside of the execution of our call to `createSomeType`, at least not directly within this class instance.

Also note: new without delete leads to memory leaks in C++. Rather, you should use smart pointers like `unique_ptr`, so that your memory is safely managed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The example was too flawed to clarify the actual question. i updated it :) (it's friday afternoon)

Comment: This does not change too much, though. In one case you will use `var` only for the initialization operation and in the other case it is part of your class' state and you should also use it later. As I see it, there is no idiomatic preference to find here but the circumstances should decide.

Comment: I have a design that is quite Similar to the [qt-xml-streambookmarks-example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-xml-streambookmarks-example.html). In this example they decided to pass in a pointer to each readfunction. When my design go to a larger scale i thought it might be more convenient to use a class member. That raised this question but it seems not to be generalized which is also a good answer.

Comment: They pass the pointer to the methods because they will pass _different_ ones. If they just had one `QTreeWidgetItem` for the entire class, an attribute might indeed make more sense.

Comment: If you look at the class `XBelReader` only `QTreeWidgetItems` (or several) are being passed. The `XBelReader`  class  shall reflect my example :)

Comment: Of course, it is always the same type. But you can call `readFolder` with item1, with item2, with item3... If `readFolder` had to refer to some attribute in your class, you would have to update your attribute before each call. This would be not a good design because it does not reflect some state of your class but is just a preparation for a function call.

Comment: Ah okay. I get the point. So changing a class attribute is in general not a good design? That actually was my idea. Seems also like a nice use case for a pointer to me.

Comment: You can change pointers in your class but just doing so for a function call makes your code less readable, prone to errors and introduces an attribute to your class that you do not need outside of a specific call. I would say an attribute should only be used if more than one set of functions that call each other use the attribute or if you want to keep the state of the attribute after these function calls